# 1 to 1 , onto functions and sets!

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Let $X$ be some set, and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ be its power set.
Let $F=\{f \mid f : X -> \{0,1\}\}$, which is the set of all functions from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$.
We define the function $\phi(f) = \{x \in X \mid f(x)=1\}$.

**Question:** Is $\phi$ one-to-one (injective), is it onto (surjective), and why ?

To be perfectly honest, I am really worried because I can hardy understand all these set notations here.

The function in order to be Onto , we need ∀ y∈Y,  ∃ χ ∈ X * f(χ) = y. So I need somehow to show that for every "y" the above is correct. I think that in our case it is not Onto. I mean, we know that f(χ)=1 . But IF χ∈Χ where X is {0,1} , if X = 0, then f(χ)=0.

Right, my mind = blown . Could anyone shed some light here plz :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's worth mentioning that $\Phi : F \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ where $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is the power set of $X$.  To prove that $\Phi$ is one-to-one, suppose that $\Phi(f) = \Phi(g)$ for some functions $f,g \in F$ (i.e., functions $f,g : X \to \{0,1\}$) and see if you can prove that $f = g$.

To show that $\Phi$ is onto, suppose that $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ (that is, $A \subseteq X$), and see if you can define a function $f : X \to \{0,1\}$ such that $\Phi(f) = A$.

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

SpamIAm's answer is very good, but my advice will be in a slightly different direction. I'll try to help with the "mind = blown" feeling you have.

Given the way the question is phrased, I recommend trying to figure out *what in the world* the question is talking about, and seeing if that helps.

You've got a set, $X$, and its power set, $\mathcal{P}$(X). Then you've got $F$, the set of all functions from your set $X$ to $\{0,1\}$.

Now, given some $f \in F$, that is, a function $f: X \to \{0,1\}$, you define $\Phi(f)$ so that $\Phi(f) = \{ x \in X\ |\ f(x)=1 \} \subseteq X$. That is, $\Phi$ comes along and, when applied to $f$, tells you all the elements in $X$ on which $f$ takes the value 1. Basically, when given a function $f$, the function $\Phi$ just spits out a particular subset of $X$. This should tell you that $\Phi$ is a function from $F$ to the power set $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

Hopefully thinking about the question in these terms makes you feel more comfortable with the situtation.

Now, for my suggestion. I wouldn't get bogged down with the "symbolic" versions of 1-1 and onto. You'll find that math is much, *much* easier when you can say in plain language what something means.

First, onto. The function $\Phi$ is *onto* if you can get any subset of $X$ from $\Phi$ by plugging in an appropriate function $f \in F$.

Second, one-to-one. The function $\Phi$ is *one-to-one* if, when plugging in different functions $f_1 \neq f_1 \in F$, you get different outputs $\Phi(f_1) \neq \Phi(f_2) \in \mathcal{P}(X)$; in this case, different subsets of $X$.

It could also help to start with a small example. Let's say $X = \{a, b\}$. Then (verify this!) we only have 4 different functions in $F$:

$f_1(a) = f_1(b) = 0$,

$f_2(a) = 0,\ f_2(b) = 1$,

$f_3(a) = 1,\ f_3(b) = 0$, and

$f_4(a) = f_4(b) = 1$.

It often helps (considerably!) if you choose a simple, less abstract example to play around with and become comfortable. Try to write down $\mathcal{P}(X)$ and $\Phi(f_i)$ for (the functions in) this example. You'll see it's not as scary as it looks!